# Android and Eclipse. Must I include service code in my app? Multiple apps are using the same service

Tags: android, eclipse, service

I'm a relative novice to Android progamming and have already asked some basic questions about services (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659622/separation-of-logic-and-gui-in-android-app-service-has-knowledge-of-app-and-sho)

This seems like a stand-alone question so I've broken it off.

I inherited some code written in Eclipse consisting of a service and app. I put the service code into a library.  In the app settings, under Android, I added the service library under the Library section so I could reference the code.  I'm not sure this is the correct way.  I also did this in the new app I built.  However, I think I'm having problems when I try to run both apps (which should use the same service) and I'm not too surprised.  I download and debug the first app and it's working fine.  The service makes a connection to an outside device via bluetooth.  When I download and debug the second app, I notice that the first app loses it's connection.  I'm guessing that the act of downloading the second app is also downloading a new copy of the service.  My specific questions are:

1. Can two apps share the same instance of a service?
2. Should I be putting the service in a library and referencing the service in both apps, or is there another (better) way?  How would I reference a third party service if I didn't have the source code?
3. The examples I looked at, all seem to have a service and activity all in the same project.  Can someone point me to a bigger example like a service with two apps that use it?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of services: Bound service and Started service. Started service is used when you need some task to be done in the background (for instance, if you need to download a file you just start a service and download this file. After that the service will stop itself or a user can cancel it sending stopService command to it). Bound services are used for long-running tasks. It can be considered as a internet service that provides some functionality and runs almost all the time. For instance, you can create a service that will provide you functionality to add two numbers.

Now the answers:

1. Yes, they can. Basically there should be only one instance of
   service in the system. But this service can have multiple threads.
2. You can implement your service as a separate application. But
   usually there is an owner app and the app that uses the service.
3. You should have a look at the Bound services.

Comment: Thanks Yury.  Re #2, will I have to reference the service in each application as a library?  And if so, will the service be restarted each time I download and debug one of the two apps?

Comment: You can implement service as a separate application, start it and use from other applications. You need to have interface of the service not the code.

Comment: Ahh, now I'm getting close!  Can you point me to an example where one has an interface for the service and it's used by an application?  Many thanks!

Comment: There is no difference between starting the service from the same application and from external application. Just in the second case you should make your service exported (externally available) with the help of appropriate intent-filter. You should read at first android documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Comment: Thanks Yury, your answer and comments got me going.  I have more questions, but I'll post them seperately.  Thanks again!